# AWS EC2 Instance: SSH connection being dropped permanently after consistent timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, tcp, sshd

I am having trouble connecting to any instances I have created with SSH. I cannot even Ping these instances (with ICMP enabled).

If I stop the instance and start it again, I can connect with SSH for approximately 60 seconds,then I get error:  "connection reset by ".

I have appropriate SSH configurations which were working for me a week ago. On one instance, I allowed all traffic from anywhere. Still cannot ping. I get Port 22 Connection timed out. 
I tried different internet connections, host computers. I get same errors for Amazon/Ubuntu AMIs.

Please find log at the bottom for example.
In the log attached, I looked at ssh config file , but didn't change anything. I tried to get some debugging info. 
I tried some different things on 2-3 other instances,  including some configuration in SSHD config file, nothing worked. 
Thank you!

Connectivity error examples:
    A.

```
$ ssh -i "ec2_key2.pem" ubuntu@ec2-52-90-56-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-90-56-88.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

B.

```
 chinmay@ubuntu:~/AWS$ ssh -Xvvv -i "ec2_key2.pem" ec2-user@ec2-54-147-245-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-147-245-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.147.245.230] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 54.147.245.230 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ec2-54-147-245-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

LOG Attached:
LOG on Amazon AMI instance. Connection resets after approximately 60 seconds.
I can stop the instance, restart it, and connect it for around one minute.

```
$ ssh -vvv -i "standard_aws_ec2.pem" ec2-user@ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com [54.159.105.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file standard_aws_ec2.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file standard_aws_ec2.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/chinm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ni9r3f3A8dvyLH655cub1AVvuCKywoTQ3Hyz7ZALZiw
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/chinm/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/chinm/.ssh/known_hosts"
The authenticity of host 'ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com (54.159.105.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ni9r3f3A8dvyLH655cub1AVvuCKywoTQ3Hyz7ZALZiw.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com,54.159.105.2' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: standard_aws_ec2.pem (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: standard_aws_ec2.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:myqjI3CrEdes0mQO+Gq9osyyAyO0ONBEjCLYuHAJM10
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com ([54.159.105.2]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Sun Nov 26 02:10:49 2017 from 198.21.199.65

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2017.09-release-notes/
4 package(s) needed for security, out of 20 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ ssh -i "standard_aws_ec2.pem" ec2-user@ec2-54-159-105-2.compute-1.amazonaws.com^C
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo sudo ufw allow 22
sudo: ufw: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo  ufw allow 22
sudo: ufw: command not found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ yum install ufw
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
You need to be root to perform this command.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo yum install ufw
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package ufw available.
Error: Nothing to do
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ss
ssh/ ssl/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ss
ssh/ ssl/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/
moduli                    ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config               ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key          ssh_host_ed25519_key
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/
moduli                    ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config               ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key          ssh_host_ed25519_key
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/ssh
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config               ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key          ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/ssh
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config               ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key          ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/ssh
ssh_config                ssh_host_ecdsa_key        ssh_host_rsa_key
sshd_config               ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub    ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
ssh_host_dsa_key          ssh_host_ed25519_key
ssh_host_dsa_key.pub      ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ sudo netstat -anp | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      2474/sshd
tcp        0     36 172.31.93.53:22             198.21.199.65:52145         ESTABLISHED 2595/sshd
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      2474/sshd
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11314  2595/sshd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     11318  2595/sshd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     11317  2597/sshd
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-93-53 ~]$ debug3: send packet: type 1
Connection reset by 54.159.105.2 port 22
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the answer to your problem but I have some suggestions you can try, let me know if they work:

1) Maybe the session is timing out due to inactivity? try: `ssh -o "ServerAliveInterval 40"` or add `ServerAliveInterval 40` to your ssh config file.

2) Try retrieving the logs for `sshd` to see whats going on.

3) Can you double check your pub/priv keys? I've seen connection refused errors when I've used the incorrect keys in the past.

4) Amazon has a list of stuff you can try do to solve the `connection timed out` issue: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout

Good luck :)